# Zend_Db_Adapter_Oracle: Select with ORDER BY, LIMIT & WHERE

Tags: php, sql, oracle, zend-framework

I'm trying to select some records from an Oracle 11g Database. The Statement is used to implement some kind of "filter" function for an HTML Table.

Requirements: limit for paging and order the filtered results.

The query is created with **Zend_Db_Select**

****Works like a charm:****

```
$select->where('APPLICATIONS LIKE ?', '%MYAPP1%');
$select->where('APPLICATIONS NOT LIKE ?', '%GENESIS%');
$select->limit(20);
```

= 1 matching result (which is ok!)

The problem occurs when I try to order the filtered result:

```
$select->order('PATH ASC');
```

= 3 matching results ??

I think it has something to do with the query generated by Zend DB Select, it looks like this:

```
 SELECT z2.*
    FROM (
        SELECT z1.*, ROWNUM AS "zend_db_rownum"
        FROM (
            SELECT "APPS".* FROM "APPS" WHERE (APPLICATIONS LIKE '%MYAPP1%') AND (APPLICATIONS NOT LIKE '%GENESIS%') ORDER BY "PATH" ASC
        ) z1
    ) z2
    WHERE z2."zend_db_rownum" BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```

- If I run the query without order everything is fine.
- If I run the query without limit everything is fine.
- If I run the query with order + limit -> wrong result.

If I take the statement and put the order after "BETWEEN 1 AND 20" it works like I want. But how to say Zend DB Select to change it?

Important: I'm doing the query against an Oracle VIEW, if I do it against a "table" it works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously Oracle's interpretation of the query is not what the Zend framework intents:
Oracle seems to associate the ROWNUM with the row number count on the ***inner query*** before ordering, so the alias zend_db_rownum delivers wrong numbers in the where clause of the *outer query*.

Since we're not in control of the way the Zend framework generates the SQL in response to the limit() instruction, the only workaround I can think of is ***skipping*** the Zend limit() instruction, and instead doing something along the lines of:

```
$select->where('APPLICATIONS LIKE ?', '%MYAPP1%');
$select->where('APPLICATIONS NOT LIKE ?', '%GENESIS%');
$select->order('PATH ASC');

$sql = $select->__toString();

$sql = "select * from (" . $sql . ") where ROWNUM between 1 and 20";

$stmt = $db->query( $sql, array());
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Of course, this workaround is **only** legitimate in case you're **not** developing cross-DB, so your code doesn't have to be DB **agnostic**.
Meaning, you will restrict your solution to Oracle if you use my suggested workaround.

Comment: I have implemented some thing like this (cast SQL to String and add the order to the end) but your suggestion looks better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you checked that there is no error in SQL generation, and really no different conditions in WHERE clause, it may be Oracle server bug. To check it, try it on different Oracle server version or different Oracle server patch level.

Comment: Sure the problem is that the order is in the "subselect" if zend would put the order at the end it will work (;

Comment: In this SQL, ORDER BY can not go outside - ROWNUM needs to be materialized on sorted lines. Can you prepare or ask some different Oracle version ? ROWNUM can be changed  with row_number() windowing function, if you can change SQL ?

Comment: igr: could explain this with some more details please?

Comment: More details about ROWNUM http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255. More about row_number() can be found following link at the begin of page. Note that docs are for 11.2 - refer to another version if your server version is different

Comment: Important: Iam doing the query against an Oracle VIEW, if i do it against an "table" it works too..